# jQuery live focus function problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, focus, live

I have some textboxes which I want to hide and then show on focus but it doesn't seem to be working properly

Here's my jQuery

```
$("#txt1").live('focus', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#txt2").show().focus();
});

$("#txt2").live('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "") {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#txt1").show();
    }
});
```

And here's my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="Test" />

<input type="password" style="display:none" id="txt2" />
```

The problem is that in Internet Explorer the `live` focus function doesn't work as expected.

It puts focus on my text box but won't enable me to type in the box unless I click it again.

I have an example [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/5rjCg/1/)

The first Test is the one that is the problem.

I added in the second one which works as expected but I need it to work using the `live` function.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using ids, can't you use $("#txt1").bind() just as effectively? Not to say that works, just curious why you use .live() here. Are the elements created after the code is run? Also bind() might work, I didn't try it.

Comment: @Henry I've never used `.bind()` before - I use `.live()` because the fields are hidden server side on load

Comment: If they're only hidden, `bind` will still work.  (Since they do exist)

Comment: They are hidden in the Asp.Net code behind so `bind()` doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I've figured out the problem - it was because I am using an Ajax update panel in my page the jQuery wasn't being loaded properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this

```
function pageLoad() {

$("#txt1").focus(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#txt2").show().focus();
});

$("#txt2").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "") {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#txt1").show();
    }
});

};
```

Instead of having it in the `document.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

`live` doesn't support `focus` and `blur`.

Use `focusin` and `focusout`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to make any difference - it works with `focus` and `blur` in safari but not in IE